# Correct Packaging

Tags: java, package

I have designed my system and I am trying to come up with a suitable packaging system.

I read that you should package classes that will change together in the same packages.

The problem I am having is that I find myself wanting to name the package after the interface that all the classes tend to implement.

For example:
I have this structure:

```
        Dimension
            ^
            |
    +-------+-------+
    |       |       |
 Cylinder  Tube   Cuboid
```

I am wanting to put them in a package `com.mycompany.dimension` but it seems strange to then import `com.mycompany.dimension.Dimension` because of the repetition?

Then I find myself wanting to have lots of nesting packages, i.e.

```
com.mycompany.car...
com.mycompany.car.wheels...
com.mycompany.car.engine...
```

Is this bad? Should I try to avoid naming packages after the top level interface?

Comment: It's perfectly fine and I don't see a real *question* here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important thing is to have some logical package structure. You could just change `dimension` to `dimensions`, because the package will contain few of them.

It is perfectly fine to have some (for example abstract?) `Dimension` class in a `dimensions` package.